# Replace a character string with a space

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a problem with characters String which i want to replace all with spaces.

I have a paragraph which contains some Strings like that `{&#12333;}`

So I want to replace them with spaces.

I used this function:

```
{text=text.replaceAll("&#[1-9];", "");}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: You are close. text=text.replaceAll("\\&#[1-9]*[^;];","");

Answer (score 1):

Your regex looks for exactly one digit. Change it to:

```
"&#[1-9]+;"
```

(note the added `+`).

Also, the `[1-9]` is probably incorrect, and should be `[0-9]` (or indeed `[0-9A-Fa-f]` if the digits are hex).

Comment: A predefined character class is probably better here: `\d` ([0-9]), `\w` ([0-9a-zA-Z]) or `\p{XDigit}` ([0-9a-fA-F]).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use

```
text = text.replaceAll("&#\\d+;", " ");
```

however in case `&#...` sequences are automatically converted into characters, use

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7F]", " ");
```